# Can't get access log to work for gunicorn

Tags: logging, gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn behind ngninx. I want to log errors in gunicorn to gunicorn-error.log and access logs to gunicorn-access.log.

I've got the errorlog working but not the access log, what am I doing wrong?

This is my gunicorn.conf.py:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8888'
backlog = 2048
workers = 3
errorlog = '/home/my/logs/gunicorn-error.log'
accesslog = '/home/my/logs/gunicorn-access.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
proc_name = 'gunicorn-my'
pidfile = '/var/run/my.pid'
```

This is the script to run gunicorn:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ENV=/home/my/env/bin/activate
GUNICORN=gunicorn_django
SETTINGS_PATH=/home/my/app/app/settings
PROJECT_PATH=/home/my/app
CONFROOT=/home/my/app/conf/gunicorn.conf.py

cd $SETTINGS_PATH
source $ENV
export PYTHONPATH=$PROJECT_PATH
exec $GUNICORN app.settings.staging -c $CONFROOT
```

It creates both gunicorn-error.log and gunicorn-access.log but only gunicorn-error.log gets any logs, eg:

```
2012-11-20 11:49:57 [27817] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
2012-11-20 11:49:57 [27817] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2012-11-20 11:49:57 [27817] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8888 (27817)
2012-11-20 11:49:57 [27817] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-11-20 11:49:58 [27825] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27825
2012-11-20 11:49:58 [27828] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27828
2012-11-20 11:49:58 [27830] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27830
```

What am I doing wrong? Anyone want to share their working gunicorn.conf.py with error logs and access logs?

Comment: I have the same question. I don't like specifying the access file location of gunicorn withing Django. It should use the gunicorn --access-log variable. But somehow I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have changed my logging configuration in Django to following and it helped:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'generic': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            '()': 'logging.Formatter',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'error_file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'generic',
            'filename': '/home/fungine/gunicorn.error.log',
        },
        'access_file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'generic',
            'filename': '/home/fungine/gunicorn.access.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'gunicorn.error': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['error_file'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['access_file'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps better to have the log there as well.

Comment: Problem with this is that the filehandlers aren't meant to be logged to via multiple processes.

Comment: Just fyi in case anyone else gets stuck on this, to specify a specific class for a Formatter, the key is `"()"` not "class", the class key is for Handlers. Mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema) in the docs.

Answer (score 24):

Specifying `'disable_existing_loggers': False` in `logging.config.dictConfig` works for me.

> **disable_existing_loggers** – If specified as `False`, loggers which exist when this call is made are left alone. The default is `True`
>   because this enables old behaviour in a backward- compatible way. This
>   behaviour is to disable any existing loggers unless they or their
>   ancestors are explicitly named in the logging configuration.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig