# Gunicorn not responding

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm using Gunicorn to serve a Django application, it was working alright till I changed its timeout from 30s to 900000s, I had to do this because I had a usecase in which a huge file needed to get uploaded and processed (process taking more than 30m in some cases) but after this change Gunicorn goes unresponsive after few hours, I guess the problem is all workers (being 30) will be busy with some requests after this amount of time, the weird thing is it happens even if I don't run that long request at all and it happens with normal exploring in django admin. I wanna know if there's a way to monitor requests on gunicorn and see workers are busy with what requests, I wanna find out the requests that's making them busy. I tried `--log-file=- --log-level=debug` but it doesn't tell anything about requests, I need more detailed logs.

Comment: My hunch is that there may be a deadlock in some of your request handling code. With a 30 second timeout, the affected workers will eventually free up. With a 0.9 megasecond timeout they effectively won't.

Comment: I see, that's why I need logs, to find out what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

From the latest Gunicorn docs, on the cmd line/script you can use:

```
--log-file - ("-" means log to stderr)
--log-level debug
```

or in the config file you can use:

```
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
loglevel = 'debug'
```

but there is no mention of the parameter format you specified in your question:

```
--log-file=- 
--log-level=debug
```

The default logging for access is 'None' ([ref](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-apps-using-gunicorn-http-server-behind-nginx)), so shot in the dark, but this may explain why are not receiving detailed log information. Here is a [sample config file](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py) from the Gunicorn source, and the latest Gunicorn [config docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html).

Also, you may want to look into [changing your logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472842/cant-get-access-log-to-work-for-gunicorn) in Django.

Comment: --log-file=- is equivalent to --log-file -, it's showing lots of logs but not the detailed logs I want. I need to know how much time each request takes to process on server.

Answer (score -1):

While I am also looking for a good answer for how to see how many workers are busy, you are solving this problem the wrong way. For a task that takes that long you need a worker, like Celery/RabbitMQ, to do the heavy lifting asynchronously, while your request/response cycle remains fast.

I have a script on my site that can take 5+ minutes to complete, and here's a good pattern I'm using:

1. When the request first comes in, spawn the task and simply return a HTTP 202 Accepted. Its purpose is "The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed."
2. Have your front-end poll the same endpoint (every 30 seconds should suffice). As long as the task is not complete, return a 202
3. Eventually when it finishes return a 200, along with any data the front-end might need.

For my site, we want to update data that is more than 10 minutes old. I pass the Accept-Datetime header to indicate how old of data is acceptable. If our local cached copy is older than that, we spawn the task cycle.

Comment: No it's not always good solution, "usually" it's right but not always. Sometimes the logic is to make user wait till the response is ready (however it takes) and show him the response. In my case I needed to do so and that's why I asked it here (anyway I'm not the one who voted down your answer)

Comment: Ok, sure. What I proposed is only usually the answer. But how do you "make the user wait"? What happens if they hit refresh? Does the job continue or do they have to start over. If it continues, how do they get a status update?

Comment: I just set up an account with Datadog. They have an integration with gunicorn that will allow you to see how many workers are busy vs. free.

Comment: the users that use this service are trained and know that they shouldn't refresh/close tab, and even if they do by accident nothing bad happens (if they rerun the task). it's a local service with few trained users.